# clustered immutant2 instances

Tags: clojure, immutant

Is there any way to run few clustered immutant2 based apps with no deploy to wildfly? I would like to test distributed cache having two REPLs opened but I see no option in immutant docs to have these 2 sessions in 1 cluster.

Looks like for immutant 1.x it was --clustered option for lein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Immutant 2, clustering is only available when running inside of WildFly. However, you can still get a repl inside WildFly - just create a "dev" war with the lein-immutant plugin, and it will start a repl for you when deployed to WildFly. You create a dev war with:

```
lein immutant war --dev
```

(assuming you are using `[lein-immutant "2.0.0"]`. See the [WildFly guide](http://immutant.org/documentation/current/apidoc/guide-wildfly.html) for instructions on starting a WildFly instance in clustered mode.